# Changing jobs on DE EU Blue Card (After transferring from another member state)

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card, poland

There are normally restrictions placed on new EU Blue cards which states that you cannot change employers within the first two years without permission from the foreigners office, but my question is, does this restriction STILL apply to those who've transferred their blue card?

I appreciate this may come across as a duplicate of existing questions, but the difference here is that the question relates to someone who has transferred an EU Blue Card from another member state after holding it in the original state for more than 2 years.

Anecdotal evidence has suggested to me that there is NO restriction and that one ought to be able to perform freelance activity too, but I'm finding it difficult to confirm this.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is only one case in the AufenthG where the time in another EU country with a Blue Card is **explicitly included** ([Section 9b(2) - Counting residence periods](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0162)). Since such an exception was **not** explicitly included in  [Section 18b(2) - Skilled workers holding a university degree](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0403) sentence 4, I would assume the time outside of Germany does not count.